# Risks of HTML/JavaScript window.opener security flaw?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, html

I do not know if you are aware of this flaw, but here is a basic example:

**somepage.html** (pointing to **malicious.html**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test">Some text<p>
    <p><a href="malicious.html">lien</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**malicious.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        var win = window.opener;
        win.document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<strong> This will be written on somepage.html</strong>";                                                                                                                         
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If we click on the link on **somepage.html**, this same page will be modified by **malicious.html**. Apart from phishing, what are the risks of this flaw?

This flaw has been patched only on Chrome and Opera.

Comment: I couldn't verify this behaviour with Firefox and Chrome (tested with local html files).

Comment: related: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/

Comment: Your code does not appear to be functional in the latest Firefox or Chome as-is, `window.opener` is only set when using `window.open` to open the link, with a link like this `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('malicious.html');">lien</a>`. Using that link, this code works in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Have you any links to the actual vulnerability here? The Same Origin Policy should prevent changes if `somepage.html` and `malicious.html` are on different domains (or origins).

Comment: @SilverlightFox Related links: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/  and https://blog.whatever.io/2015/03/07/on-the-security-implications-of-window-opener-location-replace/

Comment: That's different than setting `innerHTML` as in your question because of the SOP.

Answer (score 7):

**There is no security bug here.**

If `somepage.html` links to `malicious.html`, they are both located on the **same domain**. It is expected behaviour that the opened document `malicious.html` has a back reference via `window.opener`.

In the same way `somepage.html` could access `malicious.html` by creating a handle for the opened document:

```
var other = window.open('malicious.html')
```

This is consistent with the [Same-orign policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), that allows different documents of the same domain to interact with each other.

Your discovery would however be concerning if `http://evilhost/malicious.html` would manage to access the DOM of `http://somehost/somepage.html`, resulting in a [UXSS](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/universal-cross-site-scripting-uxss/) vulnerability.